# How to copy rows in mysql with PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following simplified table structure, its worth mentioning that the data model can be changed if there is a better way to structure this data.

```
document:
id text 
 1    test of document 1 description
id text
 2    test of document 2 description


document_section:
id document_id parent_id 
 1           1
id document_id parent_id
 2           1         1
id document_id parent_id
 3           1         2
```

Now, if I want to make a copy of the document with id 1 (from the document table) I simply make a new insert in the document table with some updated data, but how should I make a copy of the sections that makes up that document (the rows in document_section). If I take the row in the document_section table with id 1 and inserts an updated version that match the new row in the document section (document_id), how do I keep track of all the childs that maps to that row with the parent_id column?

I use PHP with PDO.

Comment: What table does parent_id refer to ?

Comment: it refers to the id of another row in the document_section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Map the old document_section IDs to the new ones in an array to keep a track of changings
- In the newly created rows, replace all `parents_id`s by their "new" equivalent.